# How to reshape table data (Pandas Dataframe) to 3D data for RNNs?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the next data:
Different users has different ids in the one common table. Object in a table is an action between System and user. It could be like : show_popup/close_popup/show_price/unsubsribe/pay etc. Also I have a time of all this actions, user static info (geo for example) and other.
All table looks like:

```
id user_id....some_static_info....popup_id action....time  <br />
1..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....28........show........23   <br />
2..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....28........close........25   <br />
4..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....27........close........27   <br />
3..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....27........show ........22   <br />
4..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....27........show ........ 10   <br />
5..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....51........show ........ 5    <br />
6..bbccabb..zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz....27........price........ 45   <br />
7..bbccabb..zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz....51........show ........ 44   <br />
.....................................................................
```

I want to teach LSTM to predict the reaction of user (actions like show_price) is positive and (usnubsribe, close_popup) is negative. So I added new column:

```
id user_id some_static_info popup_id action time target
1  aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    28     show   23    0           <- this is a single action <br />
2  aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    28     close  25    -1<br />
4  abbabab yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    27     close  27    -1<br />
3  abbabab yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    27      show  22    0<br />
4  abbabab yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    27      show  10    0<br />
5  abbabab yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    51      show  5     0<br />
6  bbccabb zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz    27      price 45    1           <- other action with user reaction<br />
7  bbccabb zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz    51      show  44    0<br />
.................................................
```

So target 0 is neutral actions and it could make influence to user for a positive or negative reaction. I want to teach LSTM on a series of previous actions to predict the reaction.

So Id like to get something like:

```
[ <br />
  [[action1] [action2] [action3] [action4] [action_target]],  <br />
  [[action12] [action11] [action8] [action_target]],<br />
  [[action14] [action16] [..] [..] [..] [..] [..]],<br />
  [[..] [..] [..] [..] [.]],<br />
]<br />
```

So timesteps will be various and and I dont know how to make it.

If there is no solution Id like to make func to create data that collect only n-samples in each series.
Like this:

```
[ <br />
  [[action1] [action2] [action3] [action4] [action_target1]],      <- n_samples = 4<br />
  [[action12] [action23] [action53] [action54] [action_target2]],<br />
  [[action13] [action24] [action36] [action44] [action_target3]],<br />
  [[..] [..] [..] [..] [.]],<br />
]<br />
```

I made  this function in the next way:

1. Sort all table by user_id, time
2. Find all unique user_id
3. For each user_id get all actions , that belong to it. (using iterrows)
4. Find all rows where target != 0
5. Find n previous rows whith target = 0
6. Collect that rows to the table

So I expect the table will be looks like

```
id user_id....some_static_info....popup_id action....time....target  <br />
1..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....28........show........23 .... 0 <br />
2..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....28........show ........24....0  <br />
4..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....27........show ........25....0  <br />
3..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....27........show ........26... 0  <br />
4..aaaaaaa..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....27........price........ 27....1  <br />
5..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....51........show ........ 1 ....0   <br />
6..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....27........show ........ 3....0   <br />
7..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....51........show ........ 5....0   <br />
7..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....51........show ........ 6....0   <br />
7..abbabab..yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy....51........unsub........ 8....-1   <br />
.....................................................................
```

After that Im going to use standart .reshape() for it with a static n.
The problem is that I dont know how to make this without pd.iterrows().
If I do it whith iterrows() the execution will take a lot of time (about a week).
Any ideas to make it faster?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/AtrCheema/dl4seq/blob/master/dl4seq/main.py#L973) function is supposed to convert a 2d array into 3d for LSTM for a time-series prediction problem. You can adopt this function for your case.

Comment: Roshin Raphel, Thanks, but its looks like it works only with constant timesteps, but I have various.